# Using keyboard interrupt to display something different than what the user typed

Tags: c, input, interrupt

In the C language, using keyboard interrupt, how can I display an alternate key from what the user typed? E.g., when I press 'Q' on the keyboard, then the screen should display 'A'.

Comment: Ugh, because it was marked as community wiki and I'm the one who edited it to be coherent, it now looks like I was the one who asked the question. That's kinda icky...

Comment: You should probably comment on the environment that you are working in.  Mac? XP? Linux?  What compiler are you using?  What are you going to be using this for?  Supplying a better context is likely to generate better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Handling keyboard interrupt is not a good idea on any platform. 
What about usb keyboards, there is no interrupt you can catch ?

For Windows OS's you probably want to write filter driver, you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177804/nt-kernel-programming#177854) replay partly relevant.
Sample of keyboard filter driver can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578.aspx).
For Linux you probably need to patch HID layer driver. Mac is out my scope completely :)

Answer (score 0):

We need a little more information about Your environment.

As far as I understand Your question, You want to replace the
keyboard interrupt handler with Your own in this way:

- Save the entry address of the original keyboard handler.
- Install Your own that calls the original and manipulates the keycode value.

However, on most modern operating systems it is much easier to define and install a new keyboard layout.